# How can I cross-compile GCC to produce libgfortran for iOS devices (arm, armv7)?

Tags: ios, gcc, fortran, llvm, cross-compiling

I need to compile Fortran-77 subroutines to be accessible on iOS. I am using GCC with the [DragonEgg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/) plugin, so I can use gfortran with the LLVM backend. I followed [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157502/40380) but I am stuck when it comes to build *libgfortran* for armv7, armv7s and arm64.

- Can I build libgfortran alone or is it always necessary to compile the GCC suite completely?
- What is the correct way of producing this library for a different target? Is it possible to use GCC for this step or do I need LLVM for the arm*-targets?

Building GCC with arm-targets using GCC I get these errors:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/out --host=arm-apple-darwin --enable-languages=fortran
make
…
make[2]: arm-apple-darwin-ar: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [libiberty.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-libiberty] Error 2
```

Building GCC with arm-targets using LLVM I have problems with configure:

```
export CC="$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang)"
export CPP="$CC -E"
export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path) -miphoneos-version-min=9.2"
export AR=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar)
export RANLIB=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ranlib)
export CPPFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path) -miphoneos-version-min=9.2"
export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path)"

./configure --prefix=/tmp/out --enable-languages=fortran --host=arm-apple-darwin --disable-shared
…
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -E
configure: error: in `/Users/timo/temp/gcc-4.8.5-build/fixincludes':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -E" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
make[1]: *** [configure-fixincludes] Error 1
```

The configure script states that

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
```

- What is meant by *If a cross compiler is detected*? How do I define the target platform correctly?
- LLVM uses *-arch armv7* etc. as target definition. What is nedded when using GCC?

Comment: I don't know about libgfortran alone, but gfortran cannot be built without also building gcc.

Comment: > How do I define the target platform correctly?

You should use --target. --host sets the host platform, i.e. the one on which the compiler will run.

Comment: @MikhailMaltsev Using --target instead of --host yields to [this error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bee6afa597903cefd7c8): `configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use --host.`

Comment: You need to compile and install *binutils* for *arm-apple-darwin* before compiling gcc, or to ensure that existing tools (ar, as, ld, etc.) are found.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Are the Apple tools found by e.g. `xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar` not capable of the _arm-apple-darwin_ target?

Comment: It might be just that the executable names do not match expectations of *configure*. You could try `export AR=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar)` or `export AR=/usr/bin/ar` before running configure.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to build cross-gcc libraries without cross binutils. [Here](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) is a good manual for building cross-gcc for arm, you can follow it.

> What is meant by If a cross compiler is detected? How do I define the
>   target platform correctly?

When configuring you should also set `--target=arm-apple-darwin`. (In my own experience I did not set `--host` at all)

```
make[2]: arm-apple-darwin-ar: No such file or directory
```

Before building arm cross-compiler target libraries you should build binutils for this target.

Can't say anything about llvm.

So just try to make all steps in the link above.

Comment: Aren't binutils provided by Apple? For example `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find ar` yields `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar`.

Comment: Building _binutils_ with `--target=arm-apple-darwin` from the development source tree works. I installed the tools to _/opt/cross/bin_. Unfortunately, GCC does not support _arm-apple-darwin_: `*** Configuration arm-apple-darwin not supported` (Output of gcc configure script).